# Unable to click on element after windows is closed - Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently unable to click on an element after a browser windows is closed in IE11.

**The problem with this windows is that it closes upon hitting "Save" button.**

There is no other way around, I have to save the changes in this window which will trigger the window to close. I believe right after that I **lose focus of the parent window**.

```
String parentWindow = FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().getWindowHandle();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver(), 50);
    By databaseSelection = By.xpath("somexpath");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(databaseSelection)).click();

    Set<String> handles =  FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    for(String windowHandle : handles)
    {
        if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
       {
            FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);

            WebElement checkboxA = FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid"));
            checkboxA.click();

        //I have tried to include .close but doesn't work. Windows closes on save.

        FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        }
```

Followed by this method:

```
Thread.sleep(5000L);

    String parentWindow = FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().getWindowHandle();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver(), 50);
    By criteriaSelection = By.xpath("somexpath");

//Here is were it fails to click on element.
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(criteriaSelection)).click();

    for (String winHandle : FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
         FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().switchTo().window(winHandle);
     }
        WebElement radioboxA = FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid"));
        radioboxA.click();
       WebElement saveSelections = FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid"));
        saveSelections.click();

        FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().close();
        FwkBase.getInstance().getDriver().switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Test fails at the beginning of the second method due to timeout. It fails waiting for the element to be clickable.

- I have tried to switchTo().activeElement(); in different places.
- If I comment the first method, the second method runs with no problems.

Please tell me it's not something obvious.

Thanks all.

Comment: Aren't you duplicating anything with `FwkBase.getInstance()` each time? Why not keep a reference to such an instance?

Comment: We can't really tell anything without the HTML, a link to the page, or more information. Does the element you are waiting for actually exist? It apparently doesn't because the script is timing out because it never becomes clickable.

Comment: Also, please fix the indent of your code. It's very hard to read and follow as is.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzGórkiewicz that just start the driver.

Comment: @Luch, and if it starts the driver too often, it can be the problem.

Comment: Hi @JeffC, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, I will try to fix that. I can't share much because of NDA. The website is on a private network. The behavior goes as follows: as soon as I save the settings, the window is closed. Right after that the application shows a "please wait" pop up and saves the changes. After that I want to click on another button so I added wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable to deal with that loading/refreshing time. If I just run the second method, there are no problems.

Comment: I don't know what to share specifically. I can probably avoid this in the test by redirecting to the website address after saving, but I'd rather find a better way.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you should click save, wait for the "please wait" popup to come and go, and then click the other button. Try writing and running that code and see if it works and let us know.